# Can I connect to remote servers and grep information using a script?

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, grep

I recently became a Sysadmin for the company I work for. One of the things I want to try and do is improve some of the processes with scripts. I am very new to bash but eager to learn and any help would be appreciated.

In my work if someone requests a `grep` we have to manually connect to the hostname and then become root and, after that perform the `grep`. This can be quite time consuming and so I started working on a script which would allow me to enter the following:

```
ssh user@hostname grep
```

The problem is I have no idea how to be able to connect to a given hostname. I would like some output when I run the script that asks me for the hostname which I type in and then asks me what I want to `grep` and from that I get my results.

Any help would be appreciated and apologies if this is a long winded post. It's my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command inside a script. $1 parameter could be the hostname and $2 the string to grep for, eg :  `myscript.sh host1 string_to_grep`

```
ssh  user@${1} "grep \"${2}\" *"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @funkyjelly I will try this now, much appreciated!